# Путаница в выводе программы

Tags: delphi

> Если сумма трёх действительных  чисел  x,y,z меньше 1 то наименьшее 
>   из трёх чисел заменить полусуммой  двух других, в противном случае 
>   заменить меньшее из x и y  полусуммой оставшихся значений.

Вот код на Delphi 7:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  x,y,z: real;
begin
    x := StrToFloat (Edit1.Text);
    y := StrToFloat (Edit2.Text);
    z := StrToFloat (Edit3.Text);

    if ((x+y+z)<1) then
    begin
        if ((x<y) and (x<z)) then
            x := (y+z)/2
        else
        begin
            if ((y<x) and (y<z)) then
            else
                z:=(y+x)/2;
        end;
    end
    else
    begin
        if (x<z) then
            x:=(y+z)/2
        else
            y:=(x+z)/2;
        end;
        Memo2.Lines.Add(' x = ' + FloatToStr(x) + ' y = ' + FloatToStr(y) + ' z = ' + FloatToStr(z))    
    end;

end.
```

Проблема в том что при вводе чисел x,y,z он путает y и z местами. Как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Если сформатировать исходник, то один косяк сразу будет виден, второй  - присмотреться надо.

Кроме того, стоит сравнивать на "меньше или равно", чтобы в `else` не получить сюрприз

```
  x := random;
  y := random;
  z := random;
  Memo1.Lines.add(Format('x %5.3f y %5.3f z %5.3f sum  %5.3f',
    [x,y,z,x+y+z]));
  if ((x + y + z) < 1) then
  begin
    if ((x <= y) and (x <= z)) then
      x := (y + z) / 2
    else
    begin
      if ((y <= x) and (y <= z)) then
        y := (z + x) / 2
      else
        z := (y + x) / 2;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    if (x <= y) then
      x := (y + z) / 2
    else
      y := (x + z) / 2;
  end;
  Memo1.Lines.add(Format('x %5.3f y %5.3f z %5.3f',[x,y,z]));
```