# Полусумма отображается в y а должен быть в x

Tags: delphi

Задача звучит так:

> Если сумма трёх действительных чисел  x,y,z меньше 1 то наименьшее из трёх чисел заменить полусуммой двух других, в противном случае заменить меньшее из x и y полусуммой оставшихся значений.

Полусумма должна быть в x, а у меня показывает в y. Как исправить?
Вот, на всякий случай код программы:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  x, y, z: real;
  C1,C2,C3:integer;
begin
Val(Edit1.Text,x,C1);
Val(Edit2.Text,z,C2);
Val(Edit3.Text,z,C3);
If (C1 = 0) and (C2 = 0) and (C3 = 0) Then
begin
  if x + y + z < 1
  then
  begin
    if int(x) < int(y) then
    begin
      if x < z then
        x := (y + z) / 2
      else
        z := (x + y) / 2;
    end
    else
    begin
      if y < z then
        y := (x + z) / 2
      else
        z := (x + y) / 2;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    if x < y then
      x := (y + z) / 2
    else
      y := (x + z) / 2;
  end;

  Memo2.Text:='X=' + floattostr(x) + ' Y=' + floattostr(y) + ' Z=' + floattostr(z);
   end
  else
  Memo2.Text:='Введите числа';
end;
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/957189/Путаница-в-выводе-программы

Comment: Через пару недель снова приходите с этим вопросом.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вроде работает: https://ideone.com/InG8As

```
program ideone;
var
  x, y, z, s: double;
  p: ^double;
begin
  readln(x, y, z);

  s := x + y + z;

  if x < y then p := @x else p := @y;
  if (s < 1) and (z < p^) then p := @z;

  p^ := (s - p^) / 2;

  writeln(x:7:4, y:7:4, z:7:4);
end.
```

```
4 2 1
 4.0000 2.5000 1.0000
```

```
0.5 0.25 0.125
 0.5000 0.2500 0.3750
```